# Error message installing Chocolatey in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to install [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) to use with PowerShell.

The recommended way to install it is copy and paste the following line.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

But I get the following error:

```
At line:1 char:13
+ @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-NoProfile' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:24
+ @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object  ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-ExecutionPolicy' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:150
+ ... nstall.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
+                    ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At line:1 char:1
+ @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@powershell' can be used only as
an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$powershell'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

ExecutionPolicy is set as RemoteSigned and I'm running Powershell v3

I tried some apply some bits of the installation code rather than the whole line, but basically, anything after @Powershell is an unexpected token.

Comment: It's a batch script. Try running the script in a `CMD` window, not in a powershell console.

Comment: In my box the line return error at `@powershell` for the incorrect use of `splatting operator @`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must start that line from cmd.exe (a "standard" command prompt), not from PowerShell.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I also had to add powershell.exe folder to the PATH variable:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;

Comment: Yep, take a look at this for the powershell command: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 5):

In PowerShell v3+ the easiest way is:

1. Open a PowerShell window (run as administrator)
2. Check the version of PowerShell is greater than 3:

   ```
    $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
   ```
3. Enable execution of PowerShell scripts?

   ```
   set-executionpolicy remotesigned
   ```
4. In PowerShell

   ```
   iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to install Chocolatey on my Windows 10 64-bit OS installation. I was getting `powershell not recognized as internal or external command`. Finally I found the solution, so to people who ever facing the exact same problem as I did, here is the solution for you.

The reason why you get such an error is because the `WindowsPowerShell` path is not set. So kindly set the `Path` as

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Go to Environment variable (see below). You see that `Path` variable, click on Edit and you see one more pop-up window, which shows a couple of paths there. Now click on New and copy-paste the above path. Close your CommandPrompt(admin) and open it again. Run the command given by Chocolatey, and now it starts downloading.

Here is a step-by-step guide:

Go to *Control Panel* → *System* → *Advanced System Settings* → *Environment Variables* → *User variable for Users* → Select *Path Variable* → click *Edit* → Click on *New* → paste this `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` → Click <kbd>OK</kbd> → you're done.