# "Cannot overwrite variable..." Error installing Chocolatey in PowerShell Win10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, chocolatey

While trying to install Chocolatey using Powershell, I run into an error saying

```
iex : Cannot overwrite variable ProxyCredential because the variable has been optimized. Try using the     New-Variable or Set-Variable cmdlet (without any aliases), or dot-source the command that you are using    to set the variable.
```

I  am using the code from the official Chocolatey install guide website. I am running PowerShell as Administrator.
Also, I am new to PowerShell so I don't really understand the error message 100%.

This is the full error:

```
iex : Cannot overwrite variable ProxyCredential because the variable has been optimized. Try using the     New-Variable or Set-Variable cmdlet (without any aliases), or dot-source the command that you are using    to set the variable.                                                                                       At line:1 char:166
+ ...  -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('ht ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (ProxyCredential:String) [Invoke-Expression], SessionStateUnaut
   horizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritableRare,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionComma
   nd
```

This is the code I use: [source](https://chocolatey.org/install#individual)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Also get the same error when trying this method: [source, 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771158/error-message-installing-chocolatey-in-powershell?newreg=2503795437b340428431afcd192fcd14)

```
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
```

#### Install using cmd.exe works just fine...

When I run the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771158/error-message-installing-chocolatey-in-powershell?newreg=2503795437b340428431afcd192fcd14) in cmd.exe as admin, it works just fine...

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

Does anybody know why it's not working in PowerShell? Or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you,
Gianni

Comment: Make sure you are running PowerShell as Administrator

Comment: I am running it as admin. Should've mentioned that in the post

Comment: See following : https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/usage/proxy-settings-for-chocolatey

Comment: Just to clarify, are you getting the error when you run the ```iex ...``` command in an **interactive** powershell session? If so, have you tried starting a new session to reset any existing context (variables, functions, etc) - e.g. at a cmd.exe prompt run "powershell.exe -noprofile" and then paste your command into the new powershell session... Does that still give the same error?

Comment: A shot in the half-dark, based on https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2280: Does `& { irm https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1  | iex }` help? It is definitely a PowerShell bug, related to DLR optimizations.